# Problema con mensajes mandados por PHPMailer caen en SPAM en hotmail

Tags: php, phpmailer, centos

Utilizamos un script de [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) en un servidor con Centos 7.0 y Postfix, para mandar correos. Nuestro servidor cuenta con llave Open DKIM y cuenta con registro SPF.

Cuando mandamos mensajes uno a uno llegan sin problemas, pero al utilizar el script siempre se van a SPAM, a menos que cada usuario agregue como remitente seguro cada cuenta.

```
<?php

include_once('fk_clases/class.phpmailer.php');//PHPMailer

$Subject = "Mensaje sobre llave DKIM y PHP";
$BodyCorreo = "Esta es una prueba para verificar la entrega de un correo con llave OpenDKIM";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Helo = "midominio.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth         = true;
$mail->Port             = 587; //puerto seguro
$mail->SMTPSecure       = 'tls'; //Conexion cifrada TLS
$mail->Host             = "mail.midominio.com";
$mail->Username         = 'micuenta@midominio.com';
$mail->Password         = 'mipassword';
$mail->AddReplyTo('micuenta@midominio.com','Dennis');
$mail->From             = 'micuenta@midominio.com';
$mail->FromName         = 'Dennis';
$mail->AddAddress('cuentadedestino@hotmail.com');
$mail->Subject          = $Subject;
$mail->DKIM_domain = 'midominio.com';
$mail->DKIM_private = 'ruta de la llave';
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'default';

$file_to_attach = '/root/cola.log';

$mail->AddAttachment('/root/cola.log', 'cola.log' );
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58864/discussion-on-question-by-dennis-isaias-cervantes-nunez-problema-con-mensajes-ma).

Comment: el problema no es del código, inscribete en MS Outlook postmaster program para ver cual es el problema: http://mail.live.com/mail/postmaster.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba que tengas el [SPF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) bien configurado, eso puede ser una de las razones por las que el correo electrónico que estas mandando caiga en spam.

Aquí te paso un [generador de SPF](http://www.spfwizard.net/es/).

También tiene que ver la reputación de la IP desde la que estés mandando el correo electrónico, de manera que aunque tenga el SPF bien configurado, si la IP del servidor desde la que lo mandas está en alguna lista negra, al pasar por ese servidor, la reputación cae.

Un par de sitios donde lo puedes mirar:

http://www.blacklistalert.org/

http://multirbl.valli.org/

http://mxtoolbox.com/

Del mismo modo, mandando un correo a esta página web, puedes ver la reputación que tiene el correo y las probabilidades de que caiga en spam. Te puede ayudar a mejorar la reputación:

http://www.mail-tester.com/

Sobre la configuración de correo que veo en el script, entiendo que te conectas al servidor SMTP correctamente porque dices que el correo llega. Bien, ¿cuando el correo llega a la cuenta destino que reputación tiene?

¿Puedes poner el código fuente del correo?

Comment: Te refieres al encabezado que queda en hotmail cuando llega el mensaje???

Comment: Eso es, para ver las cabeceras que están llegando, así como la puntuación.

Comment: hola tambien te comento que cuando agrego la cuenta de origen como remitente seguro llegan sin problemas pero cuando lo hago de una nueva cuenta ahi siempre caen en espam

Comment: No me deja copiarlo por entero acá pero si me das un email puedo mandartelo Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tus correos se van a spam porque no tiene autenticación SMTP pero en tu código veo que si esta.. si lo estas ejecutando mediante un host verifica que el hosting dodne se encuentra alojado tenga buena reputación porque sino la ip se cataloga como másiva y empiezan a lelgar los mail al spam.

Si persistes con ese problema usa esta librería 
http://www.developarts.com/proyectos/nomad-mimemail/

Y si no se soluciona el inconveniente es por la reputación del host.

Comment: Te equivocas, está usando autenticación: Received: from aaaa.com (unknown [aa.aa.aa.aa])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher AECDH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)), por lo que no es la razón por la que llega a spam. Tampoco está en ninguna lista negra (he probado varios servicios para comprobarlo).